# DBNull exception in query expression

Tags: c#, linq, dbnull, query-expressions

I have this query expression, to concatenate some values for data validation

```
result.AddRange(from string dr in ercDt
   select dc.Ordinal.ToString() + "|" + dr);
```

Having that ercDt[0] is DBNull, and has no more rows, i'm getting this error

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.

I've tried this

```
result.AddRange(from string dr in ercDt
where dr.Any(x => x != null)
select dc.Ordinal + "|" + dr);
```

and this

```
result.AddRange(from string dr in ercDt
where ercDt.Any(x => x != null)
select dc.Ordinal + "|" + dr);
```

and this

```
result.AddRange(from string dr in ercDt
where !(dr is DBNull)
select dc.Ordinal + "|" + dr);
```

And no luck,

How can I prevent this error from happening? I need to query no nulls at all, so my desired output in this case would be no records.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Based on the confusion I'll describe better my case:

'ercDt' is a List coming from a linq query (the result of that linq query is strings and very rare cases of DBNull) converted to List (with ToList() method), so I can cast 'dr' to string, but my problems comes from the DBNull values

Comment: If `dr` is a `DataRow` that doesnt work anyway. You are casting the `DataRow` to `String` which should give you a runtime error. What is `ercDt`(it it was a `DataTable` you'd get a compiler error)? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Thanks Tim, ercDt is a List<object> but those objects I assumed as strings (result of a linq query from a datatable and converted with .ToList() method) that's why I cast as string straight from ercDt.
What I'm trying to do is concatenate the contents from ercDt to the ordinal of a higher level datatable (dc is from another Datatable)

Answer (score 0):

If `dr` is a `DataRow` that doesnt work anyway. You are casting the `DataRow` to `String` which should give you a runtime error. What is `ercDt`(it it was a `DataTable` you'd even get a compiler error)? I'll give it a try anyway.

So presuming that `ercDt` is a `DataTable`, i guess you want all fields with a value, so those which are not  `DBNull.Value`. Use [`DataRow.IsNull`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.isnull%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
DataColumn dc = ercDt.Columns[0]; // i don't know which column you use
var fields = from dr in ercDt.AsEnumerable()
             where !dr.IsNull(dc.Ordinal)
             select dc.Ordinal + "|" + dr[dc].ToString();
result.AddRange(fields);
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, ercDt is a List<object> but those objects I assumed as strings (result of a linq query from a datatable and converted with .ToList() method) that's why I cast as string straight from ercDt. What I'm trying to do is concatenate the contents from ercDt to the ordinal of a higher level datatable (dc is from another Datatable)

Comment: @culebrin: maybe my answer is helpful anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
result.AddRange(from string dr in ercDt
select ((dc.Ordinal == null) ? string.Empty() : dc.Ordinal.ToString()) + 
    "|" + ((dr == null) ? string.Empty() : dr));
```

Comment: Thanks Scottie, your answer gives me an idea of restrict the list before querying it. I'll let you know...